# Passing custom headers with Backbone.js collection.sync

Tags: api, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

Without having to implement a custom `collection.sync`, is it possible to send custom headers to the server when Backbone.js calls its `sync` method?

That is, I want to pass a customer header to the server when I perform an operation, like `collection.fetch`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily extend the `.sync` method without having to re-write it

```
myApp.originalSync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    options || (options = {});
    options.headers = { "your": "custom header" };
    return myApp.originalSync(method,model,options);
};
```

Comment: Thanks. If I don't want the header to be used when syncing all collections/models, can I just spend specific headers for certain collections as an example?

Comment: Just override the `.sync` method of the appropriate collection(s). Instead of `Backbone.sync` in the snippet above, use `MyCollection.sync`.